# Ajax shopping cart with session_id() as unique identifier?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cart

I am building an ajax shopping cart and am thinking of storing carts in my db with session_id() as the unique identifier.

All I want is to avoid page refreshes and avoid requiring the user to log in.  Not expecting a ton of traffic.  I don't care that the session is lost when browser is closed, so I guess I don't see a need for cookies like: [Storing shopping cart items into cookies and database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988671/storing-shopping-cart-items-into-cookies-and-database).

Any pitfalls to my approach?

Comment: Why not store carts in session?

Comment: @Kai I guess I don't see why not db?  Feels more straightforward to me.  Like for updating quantities, for instance.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Doing it the way you suggest is more complicated than simply using session.  For instance, consider what do you do when sessions get deleted?  You'll have to clean up your database periodically. And you're kind of duplicating the functionality of session.  I'm not sure I understand why you think updating quantities and such would be more straightforward either -- all you have to do with session is set the data `$_SESSION[$productId]['quantity'] = 5`, or however you'd end up formatting your session data, whereas with the database, you have to write out actual database queries.

Comment: I suppose I'm just used to manipulating db, so it's familiar.  But your point is well taken.